# Best way to get the first field of each element of an array of STRUCT without unnesting in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a table with a layout similar to this one in BigQuery:

```
SELECT
    1 AS id,
    [
      STRUCT("ham" as name, 1 AS qty, 10 AS cost),
      STRUCT("cheese" as name, 2 AS qty, 20 AS cost),
      STRUCT("eggs" as name, 3 AS qty, 30 AS cost)
    ] AS entry
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT
    2 AS id,
    [
      STRUCT("another_ham" as name, 4 AS qty, 40 AS cost),
      STRUCT("another_cheese" as name, 5 AS qty, 50 AS cost),
      STRUCT("another_eggs" as name, 6 AS qty, 60 AS cost)
    ] AS entry
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT
    3 AS id,
    [
      STRUCT("yet_another_ham" as name, 7 AS qty, 70 AS cost),
      STRUCT("yet_another_cheese" as name, 8 AS qty, 80 AS cost),
      STRUCT("yet_another_eggs" as name, 9 AS qty, 90 AS cost)
    ] AS entry
```

ie. A table with an ID and a column with arrays of structs.

I want to create an array column for each ID that contains only the name from each struct, in list comprehension i would do:

```
SELECT id, [name for name in entry] AS name_array FROM data
```

I know i can do something like this using UNNEST:

```
SELECT
  id,
  ARRAY_AGG(entry.name)
FROM data
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(entry) AS entry
GROUP BY id
```

This solution works as expected, however this solution deaggregates and then immediately after aggregates the data using the same column (ID) so this seems unnecessary and expensive when the number of rows increases.

I want to know if there is a better way to do this, this would be really easy in python for example but i cannot find the right tools in BigQuery